# Sklearn regression with clustered data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cluster-analysis, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run a multinomial `LogisticRegression` in `sklearn` with a clustered dataset (that is, there are more than 1 observations for each individual, where only some features change and others remain constant per individual).

I am aware in `statsmodels` it is possible to account for this the following way:

```
mnl = MNLogit(x,y).fit(cov_type="cluster", cov_kwds={"groups": cluster_groups)
```

Is there a way to replicate this with the sklearn package instead?

Comment: I know how to run a multinomial logit in sklearn, I want to find out how to run one on a clustered dataset.

Answer (score -1):

In order to run multinomial Logistic Regression in sklearn, you can use the `LogisticRegression` module and then set the parameter `multi_class` to `multinomial`.

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: I know how to run a multinomial logit in sklearn, I want to find out how to run one on a clustered dataset, do you know if it can be done in sklearn?